# React Select set wrong value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm getting crazy with this. I'm using [react-select](https://react-select.com) for my app and since I have a huge form I created a small component to wrap the Selects like that:

```
const SelectField = (props) => {
  const { id } = props;
  return (
    <Select
      id={id}
      value={this.state[id]}
      onChange={(value) => { this.onChangeValue({ target: { id, value } }); }}
      options={options[id]}
      placeholder="Please select..."
    />
  );
};
```

And I use it like that:

```
<SelectField id="gender" />
```

The `onChangeValue` method handle the `setState` of all the inputs:

```
onChangeValue(e) {
  const { id, value } = e.target;
  this.setState({ [id]: value });
}
```

Since `react-select` for some weird reason doesn't return the `event` I just emulated it passing the data I need.

This version of the code seems to work as expected, if I select something I can correctly see the right value in the input. Unfortunately in the state that value is not correct, it should be a `string` but it is the entire option: `{ label: 'Gender', value: 'Male'}`.

So here I already don't understand how `react-select` can display `Male` if the result of the value is this object.

If I change the `onChange` like the following:

```
onChange={(value) => { this.onChangeValue({ target: { id, value: value.value } }); }}
```

This would make more sense to me, since I directly pass the right value to the value to set in the state.

Suddenly this doesn't work at all. If I select an option the input still display the placeholder but, yes, the state is correct.

I tried to add several workarounds and none is working as expected.

I need to display the selected value to the select and also to have the state, for gender in my example, to be a string with the value, not the entire object...

What I'm doing wrong here? Ideas? Cheers

Comment: You seem to declare SelectField as a stateless component, then call .setState in there, that won't work.

Comment: Can you provide an example about that, thanks!

Comment: When you declare a react component as a function (here: `const SelectField = (props) => ...`) you declare it as *stateless*, this means you do not have a this.state, actually since it's an arrow function you do not even have a `this` at all. I would refer you to the react documentation to learn about this. The other way to declare a component is as a class `class SelectField extends React.Component { ...` and there you have access to `this.setState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more in-detail answer from my earlier comment:

```
class SelectField extends React.Component {

    state = {
        id: this.props.id
    };

    onChangeValue = id => value {
        this.setState({ [id]: value });
    }

    render() {
        const { id } = this.state;
        return (
            <Select
                id={id}
                value={this.state[id]}
                onChange={this.onChangeValue(id)}
                options={options[id]} // unsure where options came from.
                placeholder="Please select..."
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, this make sense to me... But then I don't know how to get the values in the main component... since the state values are stored in a separate component.... I'm pretty sure I'm missing something...

Comment: Managed to let it work with callbacks and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately react-select wants the whole object as the selected value. You essentially have 2 options:

1. Store the whole object in state like you currently are. You can just return the value to any other interested party.
2. Store only the value in state. When you pass the value in to react-select you will need to do a find on your options

   value={options[id].find(opt => opt.value === this.state[id].value)}

Also, there is no reason to be storing it in state[id]. You could just store it as state.value or selectedValue since it's the only thing that will be in state for that component.

Comment: Can you please enhance your answer with example so that I can better understand? Thanks for your help

Comment: Honestly I would just continue to store the whole option like you're doing right now. Is there a reason why you don't want to store the whole thing?

Comment: When I save it I can not pass the entire state, but I have to check for all selects and get the value...

Comment: Your wrapper only has a single thing in state at any given point. Your caller will need to pass an onChange handler too. You could just call that with the value from that object and keep the whole object in state internally. e.g. this.props.onChange(this.state[id].value)